# In Python, when to modify self and when to return new instance?

Tags: python, class, instance

I am very often in a great dilemma, when should a class modify itself and when to return a new modified instance.

Lets say I want to program a simple sequence library.

```
class Seq:
   def __init__(self, seq):
      self.seq = seq
```

and then I want to rename the elements in the sequence, there are two options for this method in Seq:

```
def rename(lookup):
   self.seq = [lookup[e] for e in self.seq]
```

or

```
def rename(lookup):
   return Seq([lookup[e] for e in self.seq])
```

I will be dealing with more complicated structures, for exampke, if I am creating a graph and I want to put it into unique canonical (unique vertex enumeration) form, should it put itself in this form or return a new instance. What are most common practices about this and when to choose the two options?

My thinking is this: you have to participate what the users will have most use of. But is this

```
def rename(lookup, create_new_instance = False):
   if create_new_instance:
      return [lookup[e] for e in self.seq]
   else:
      self.seq = [lookup[e] for e in self.seq]
```

a good practice?

Or should I just implement two different methods, one as a static, that returns new object and one non-static that modifies itself? Like list.sort() and sorted(list)? But then there is a lot of overhead if I have a lot of methods that modify the object.

Comment: I don't think there is a correct answer to this. It's up to you. There are built in methods that modify the object itself and plenty of built in methods that return a version of the modified object. I feel like the best question you can ask is: "What would a user of this class expect to happen"? I do like your `create_new_instance` parameter idea. Personally I would call it `in_place` :)

Comment: That really depends on your use case and requirements. But for me, generally, if I'm changing something I change it, and if I want something new I create something new. If conceptually you are changing an object, it does not really make sense to create a new one. Unless you have a reason to have both the old and the new one.

Comment: @JNevill: There is a pattern to it though; returning modified objects is done by top level functions and methods on immutable types. Mutable type methods basically *never* return a new copy with mutations applied (aside from the `copy` method itself, which doesn't mutate, only copies). You're not required to follow the design Python built-ins use, but you ought to be able to describe a benefit that is worth the cost of clashing with expectations from existing built-in types.

Comment: Oh, a side-note: If `self.seq` is intended to be public, you should assume others might have aliases to it, and if they should modify in tandem, `self.seq = [lookup[e] for e in self.seq]` should be `self.seq[:] = [lookup[e] for e in self.seq]` (the `[:]` means it reassigns the contents in place, so aliases will reflect the change, instead of replacing the old `list` with a new `list`, which won't affect aliases). If it's not intended to be public, give it a name that says that, e.g. `self._seq` instead of `self.seq` (leading underscore is convention for "not part of public API").

Comment: In either case, `rename` should be a method of the `Seq` class, not a standalone function.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, for built-ins the rule is:

1. If the class instances are logically mutable, and the method makes sense as a mutation method, *only* make mutating methods (and they always return `None`, so there is no confusion as to whether they returned themselves mutated, or a mutated copy)
2. If the class instances are logically immutable, you have no choice, all such "mutating" methods return new objects (note: New objects of that type typically; `rename` returning an unrelated `list` instead of a new `Seq` would be weird)

Do *not* have methods that vary in the return like that based on the argument, that's pointlessly confusing, especially if people pass it positionally; quick, what does `obj.rename(xyz, True)` mean as opposed to `obj.rename(xyz, False)`? It's more work for you, and more work for them, just don't do it.

Since your class is logically mutable, follow the rules for #1. Don't make a bunch of variant methods though, just define slicing (so they can do `myseq[:]` for a shallow copy) and/or a `copy` method (`list` provides both, you may as well). If the user wants to preserve the original thing, they copy first, then mutate the result. Makes it much clearer in use, and avoids massive code duplication.

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on what you want the user to be aware of in your structure.

On one hand, modifying `self.seq` ensures that you keep entire control of your structure, because you can control how this field is accessed (through properties for example)

On the other hand, returning the collection directly allows the user to make any transformation on it, so you will not keep control of what appends to `seq`. It can entirely break you class logic if the right checks are not done.